# How to use sed to replace &amp; with &

Tags: unix

Hi I have a file and want to replace  all `& amp;` with `&` using sed. Can you tell me how to use sed for this, as the following command did not worked for me.

```
sed 's/& amp;/&/g' BX-Books.csv > r1.txt
```

**Here & and amp have no space between.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on the title of the question, you need to escape `&`:

```
sed 's/\&amp/\&/g' BX-Books.csv > r1.txt
```